# Kotlin and Android configuration Debug

Tags: javascript, kotlin-android-extensions

I just downloaded Android Studio and Java JDK. So, when I create My Application and it launches file such as MainActivity.kt and instead I want to use /java and I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, you should create a MainActivity.java class like normal, and in your manifest where your MainActivity.kt is being used replace it with you MainActivity.java. That should launch your java activity as opposed to the Kotlin one.

Answer (score 0):

While you are creating a new project you should mark the "Include Kotlin support" checkbox on page. So the kotlin dependencies won't be added to your project.

[image]